# Could not find matching constructor for: jxl.write.Label(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Tags: java, api, groovy, automation, soapui

I am getting the exception

ERROR:Exception happened: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: jxl.write.Label(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

When I try to write the response value to excel using groovy.
In this groovy script, I am trying to write the status(pass/fail) of soap request to an excel along with the request and response node values

Here is my code

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestRunContext
import jxl.*
import jxl.write.*
import jxl.write.Label

def TestCase = context.testCase
PropertiesTestStep = TestCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")
Stop = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("End").toString()

if(Stop!="True"){
def response = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('GetSectors').getPropertyValue("response")
def samplexmlreq=new XmlHolder(response)
def count = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("Counter")
def result
def row = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("row")
def column = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("column")
def flag=0
WritableWorkbook wb   
WritableSheet sheet
  
try
{
         def token = samplexmlreq.getNodeValue("/*:Envelope/*:Body/tRisePtz:GetSectorsResponse/tRisePtz:Sectors["+count+"]/tRisePtz:SectorToken")
        def name = samplexmlreq.getNodeValue("/*:Envelope/*:Body/tRisePtz:GetSectorsResponse/tRisePtz:Sectors["+count+"]/tRisePtz:SectorName")      
        def leftLimit = samplexmlreq.getNodeValue("/*:Envelope/*:Body/tRisePtz:GetSectorsResponse/tRisePtz:Sectors["+count+"]/tRisePtz:LeftLimit")
        def rightLimit = samplexmlreq.getNodeValue("/*:Envelope/*:Body/tRisePtz:GetSectorsResponse/tRisePtz:Sectors["+count+"]/tRisePtz:RightLimit")
        def TokenFromProperies = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("SectorToken")
        def NameFromProperies = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("SectorName")
        def LeftLimitFromProperies = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("LeftLimit")
         def RightLimitFromProperies = PropertiesTestStep.getPropertyValue("RightLimit")    
         if(name == NameFromProperies && leftLimit == LeftLimitFromProperies && 
            rightLimit == RightLimitFromProperies )
         {
            result  = "Passed"
         }
         else
         {
            result  = "Failed"
         }
      def projectPath = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context).projectPath
      def folderPath = projectPath + "/SoapUIResults/SectorOSDActions/";
      def resultFolder = new File(folderPath);  
      
      if(!resultFolder.exists())
      {
        resultFolder.mkdirs();
      }
      def file = new File(resultFolder,"TestSuite_Report.xls").exists()
      //Creating workbook if not exists
      if(!file){
      wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(resultFolder ,"TestSuite_Report.xls")) 
      }
      else
      {
         wb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(resultFolder,"TestSuite_Report.xls"))  
      }
      //Creating sheet if not exist
     if (wb.getNumberOfSheets() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
           if (wb.getSheetName(i).equals("GoToSector")) {
                sheet = wb.getSheet("GoToSector");
                flag=1
                break;
            } 
        }
    }
  
    if(flag == 0){
        sheet = wb.createSheet("GoToSector",0);
     Label label = new Label(0, 0, "Type"); //column=0=A,row=0=1
    sheet.addCell(label);
    Label label1 = new Label(1, 0, "SectorName");
    sheet.addCell(label1);
    Label label2 = new Label(2, 0, "LeftLimit");
    sheet.addCell(label2);
    Label label3 = new Label(3, 0, "RightLimit");
    sheet.addCell(label3);     
    }
          
    Label label4 = new Label(0,row,"Request")
    sheet.addCell(label4);
    Label label5 = new Label(column+1,row,NameFromProperies)
    sheet.addCell(label5);
    Label label6 = new Label(column+2,row,LeftLimitFromProperies)
    sheet.addCell(label6);
    Label label7 = new Label(column+3,row,RightLimitFromProperies)
    sheet.addCell(label7);
    Label label8 = new Label(0,row,"Response")
    sheet.addCell(label8);
    Label label9 = new Label(column,row+1,name)
    sheet.addCell(label9);
    Label label10 = new Label(column,row+2,leftLimit)
    sheet.addCell(label10);
    Label label11 = new Label(column,row+3,rightLimit)
    sheet.addCell(label11);
    Label label12 = new Label(0,row,"Status")
    sheet.addCell(label11);
    Label label13 = new Label(column,row,result)
    sheet.addCell(label11);
     wb.write()  //Getting error if I comment this
    wb.close()  //getting error if I comment this
    
 PropertiesTestStep.setPropertyValue("row",row+1)  
 PropertiesTestStep.setPropertyValue("column",column+1)

  //  WritableSheet sheetToEdit = wb1.getSheet("Sheet1");
  //  WritableCell cell;
                
}
catch(exc)
{
   log.error("Exception happened: " + exc.toString());
}

finally{
    wb.write();
    wb.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Show us your code so that we can help you.

Comment: @ou_ryperd I have updated the question and added the code. Plz try to solve it

Comment: One more query. Can we set font type Bold for titles and font color red/green for the result values using groovy

Comment: Yes you can. You'll have to look at the [API docs](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/format/package-summary.html) and see what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error message carefully it tells you what's wrong:

```
Could not find matching constructor for: jxl.write.Label(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

You're passing `(int, String, String)`, looks like it could be at `label4`

[Label](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/write/Label.html#constructor_summary) takes three parameters:

`jxl.write.Label(int column, int row, java.lang.String content)`

I haven't tested it, but you should be able to get it to work by converting the string row number to an int with [`parseInt(str)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_parseint.htm)